# Keyboard short cut to skip back 5-10 seconds in iTunes TV show?

Tags: itunes, video, shortcut

When I'm playing music I can hit <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>  (or Right Arrow, <kbd>→</kbd>) to skip backward (or forward) about 5 seconds. Now I'm watching a TV show for the purpose of learning a language and I like to be able to do this, but <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> doesn't do anything.

Is there a good keyboard shortcut for jumping back 5-10 seconds while watching a video?

iTunes 12.8.0.150, macOS 10.13.6.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that this is possible using AppleScript, and when it comes to AppleScript and iTunes, DougScripts.com is always the place that I check first, which led me to this:

**Skip Back or Ahead:** https://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=skipbackorahead

I don't know if his scripts control video as well as audio, but if they don't, I bet he'd know how to adapt it.